# Erro no if e erro System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'

Tags: c#, .net

Estou criando uma calculadora e estou com dois problemas: o If assim como deixei informado em forma de comentário na soma funciona perfeitamente mas na subtração ele continua somando e nas outras duas operações da erro. Além disso, ainda no if  a partir da subtração ele consta o erro System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'

Aqui está meu código:

```
 using System;
 using System.Globalization;
 using System.Web;
 using System.Windows.Forms;

 namespace resolução_calculadora
 {
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public string valor1;
        public string valor2;
        public string operacao;
        public double resultado;
       
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {       
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {    
        }

        private void button15_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "0";
        }

        private void button14_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            valor1 = textBox1.Text;
            operacao = "DIVISAO";
            textBox1.Text = "";
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "/";
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "5";
        }

        private void button16_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + ",";
        }

        private void button11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            valor1 = textBox1.Text;
            operacao = "MULTIPLICACAO";
            textBox1.Text = "";
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "X";
        }

        private void button12_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            valor1 = textBox1.Text;
            operacao = "SUBTRACAO";
            textBox1.Text = "";
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "-";
        }

        private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            valor1 = textBox1.Text;
            operacao = "SOMA";
            textBox1.Text = "";
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "+";
        }

        private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "8";
        }

        private void button7_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "1";
        }

        private void button6_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "2";
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "3";
        }

        private void button5_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "4";
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "6";
        }

        private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "7";
        }       

        private void button13_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            valor2= textBox1.Text;

            if (operacao == "SOMA")
             {
                resultado = Convert.ToDouble(valor1) + Convert.ToDouble(valor2);
                textBox1.Text = resultado.ToString();
            }/////////subtracao está somando e os demais da erro
            else if (operacao == "SUBTRACAO")
            {
                resultado = Convert.ToDouble(valor1) - Convert.ToDouble(valor2);
                textBox1.Text = resultado.ToString();
            }
            else if (operacao == "MULTIPLICACAO")
            {
                resultado = Convert.ToDouble(valor1) * Convert.ToDouble(valor2);
                textBox1.Text = resultado.ToString();
            }
            else 
            {
                resultado = Convert.ToDouble(valor1) / Convert.ToDouble(valor2);
                textBox1.Text = resultado.ToString();
            }
        }

        private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "0";
        }
    }
}
```

[Na imagem mostra um terceiro erro que também não consegui solucionar.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WT5bb.png)

Comment: Boa tarde Thais. A sua calculadora realiza operações apenas entre 2 valores, certo?

Comment: Sim, apenas entre 2 valores.

Answer (score -2):

Acho que achei onde você está tendo o problema!

Quando você clica nos botões das operações, seleciona o segundo número e clica para obter o resultado, o texto da operação "vai junto" com o segundo valor.

Por exemplo, se você realizar a soma de 10 e 2, verá que as variáveis estarão assim:

```cs
valor1 = "10"
valor2 = "+2"
```

Quando a variável valor2 é convertida para double, o sinal de adição passa a indicar que o número é positivo. E nesse exemplo 10 + (+2) = 12. Por isso que a adição funciona.

Mas vamos simular a subtração de 10 - 2. Se você olhar as variáveis, elas estarão assim:

```cs
valor1 = "10"
valor2 = "-2"
```

Neste exemplo 10 - (-2) resultará em 12, pois o famoso "menos com menos = mais" e acaba realizando a operação de soma ao invés de subtrair os números.

Agora quando você escolhe a multiplicação ou a divisão, os caracteres "X" e "/" são colocados junto do segundo valor.

Por exemplo, simulando a divisão de 10 / 2, você verá que as variáveis estarão assim:

```cs
valor1 = "10"
valor2 = "/2"
```

Nesse caso a operação de conversão do valor2 para double ficará inválida pois não existe um número double que comece com o "/".

Para corrigir o problema você pode optar por **não** inserir no textBox1 o sinal da operação selecionada. Dessa forma você não terá mais os problemas mencionados.

Bônus:

Mas e se você quiser trabalhar com números negativos?

Uma dica simples é adicionar um novo botão com o texto "+/-".

Ao clicar nesse botão você irá mudar o sinal do número.

Exemplo de implementação:

```cs
private void btn_pos_neg_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var sinalAtual = "+";
    
    // Verificamos se o valor atual da caixa de texto NÃO está vazio
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_nums.Text))
    {
        // Se não estiver vazio, então carregue o primeiro caracter do texto
        // Dica: uma string também pode ser considerada como um array de char
        sinalAtual = txt_nums.Text[0];
        
        // Se o valor do sinal for de "número positivo"
        if (sinalAtual == "+")
        {
            // Então vamos substituir pelo sinal de "número negativo"
            sinalAtual = "-";
        }
        else
        {
            // Se o sinal for de "número negativo"
            // Então vamos substituir pelo sinal de "número positivo"
            sinalAtual = "+";
        }
    }
    
    txt_nums.Text = sinalAtual + txt_nums.Text.Substring(1);
}
```

Existem outras maneiras de construir uma calculadora e manipular as operações, números negativos e etc. O jeito que eu fiz é apenas um exemplo bem simples em que você pode estar se inspirando.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

Ao que tudo indica você está utilizando o TextBox `textBox1` como "visor" da sua calculadora.

Contudo, dentro do método `button13_Click`, que provavelmente é o método do botão "=" da sua calculadora, você pega o valor que está no seu visor `textBox1` e atribui para a variável `valor2`:

```
valor2= textBox1.Text;
```

E, logo abaixo, para fazer o seu cálculo, você tenta converter esse valor para um double:

```
Convert.ToDouble(valor2)
```

E é aqui que está o problema. Como você salvou na variável `valor2` o texto que estava no seu visor `textBox1`, você está tentando converter, por exemplo, a `string` "8 + 8" para `double`. E isso não vai acontecer, devido ao fato de ter um caracter que é impossível ser convertido para número, que é o "+".

Para corrigir este problema, optei por adicionar uma pequena lógica ao clicar nos números para verificar se podemos limpar o visor e, além disso, na hora do cálculo optei por trabalhar com a mesma string utilizada anteriormente no `textBox1` e usar a função `Split` para separar os números e realizar a operação.

O código ficou assim:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private string operacao;
    private string valor1;
    private string valor2;
    private double resultado;
    private bool calculado;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // Click do número 0 (button)
    private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Caso o cálculo já foi realizado, podemos zerar o visor
        if (calculado)
        {
            calculado = false;
            textBox1.Text = string.Empty;
        }

        // Atualiza o visor
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "0";
    }

    // Click do número 1 (button)
    private void button7_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (calculado)
        {
            calculado = false;
            textBox1.Text = string.Empty;
        }

        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "1";
    }

    // Click do número 2 (button)
    private void button6_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (calculado)
        {
            calculado = false;
            textBox1.Text = string.Empty;
        }

        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "2";
    }

    // Click do número 3 (button)
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (calculado)
        {
            calculado = false;
            textBox1.Text = string.Empty;
        }

        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "3";
    }

    // Click do número 4 (button)
    private void button5_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (calculado)
        {
            calculado = false;
            textBox1.Text = string.Empty;
        }

        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "4";
    }

    // Click do número 5 (button)
    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (calculado)
        {
            calculado = false;
            textBox1.Text = string.Empty;
        }

        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "5";
    }

    // Click do número 6 (button)
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (calculado)
        {
            calculado = false;
            textBox1.Text = string.Empty;
        }

        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "6";
    }

    // Click do número 7 (button)
    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (calculado)
        {
            calculado = false;
            textBox1.Text = string.Empty;
        }

        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "7";
    }

    // Click do número 8 (button)
    private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (calculado)
        {
            calculado = false;
            textBox1.Text = string.Empty;
        }

        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "8";
    }

    // Click do número 9 (button)
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (calculado)
        {
            calculado = false;
            textBox1.Text = string.Empty;
        }

        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "9";
    }

    // Click da operação de divisão (button)
    private void button14_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        operacao = "/";
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + " / ";
    }

    // Click da operação de multiplicação (button)
    private void button11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        operacao = "x";
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + " x ";
    }

    // Click da operação de subtração (button)
    private void button12_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        operacao = "-";
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + " - ";
    }

    // Click da operação de adição (button)
    private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        operacao = "+";
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + " + ";
    }

    // Click da vírgula (button)
    private void button16_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + ",";
    }

    // Click do igual/calcular (button)
    private void button13_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        calculado = true;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(operacao))
        {
            /*
             * Para pegar o primeiro valor inserido, utilizamos a função Split que separa a string utilizando um caracterer como divisor e retorna um array/vetor com o resultado.
             * Como apenas é permitida operação com 2 números, obrigatoriamente o array irá retornar sempre 2 posições, 0 e 1.
             * O primeiro valor é a posição 0 do vetor.
             * O segundo valor é a posição 1 do vetor.
             */
            valor1 = textBox1.Text.Split(char.Parse(operacao))[0];
            valor2 = textBox1.Text.Split(char.Parse(operacao))[1].Replace($" {operacao} ", string.Empty);

            if (operacao == "+")
            {
                resultado = double.Parse(valor1) + double.Parse(valor2);
            }
            else if (operacao == "-")
            {
                resultado = double.Parse(valor1) - double.Parse(valor2);
            }
            else if (operacao == "x")
            {
                resultado = double.Parse(valor1) * double.Parse(valor2);
            }
            else
            {
                resultado = double.Parse(valor1) / double.Parse(valor2);
            }

            // Colocamos null após realizar a operação para ser possível iniciar uma nova
            operacao = null;
        }

        textBox1.Text = resultado.ToString();
        valor1 = string.Empty; 
        valor2 = string.Empty;
        resultado = 0;
    }
}
```

---

**Notas**

- Coloquei alguns comentários no código para explicar o que foi feito;
- Tentei não fugir muito da sua lógica inicial;
- Uma breve explicação sobre o método `Split` utilizado além do que foi comentado no código:

> O método Split identifica substrings que são delimitados por um ou
> mais caracteres especificados em um array e então coloca as subtrings
> em um array de strings.